# Paypal PAYOUT_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: php, paypal, payout

My sandbox account return this error when creating a payout

```
{
    "name": "PAYOUT_NOT_AVAILABLE",
    "message": "You live in a country that is not allowed to send this payout.",
}
```

This error is not listed in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors

The account is configured in México (MX) and the official documentation includes MX in the payouts docs.

Am I missing something? Can't find any doc that excludes specific countries.
Just some exceptions for Argentina, Brazil and Malaysia.

It also defiens Mexican currency in the features
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/#payouts-features

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: As far as I remember this happened because I was trying to send money to a PayPal account that was not configured as "Enterprise" so it was not a purchase or payout. I don't know if it is because of the implementation in my country.

Comment: so you need to register sellers or some type of associate entity and you're only able to send to those?

Comment: Yeah you need to follow this documentation to find out if the implementation of the "bussines" platform fits your needs https://www.paypal.com/us/brc/article/enterprise-solutions-payments-101

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to find a similar endpoint but the weird thing is that it's not listed in the main APIs menu but it seems to be working, for reference check:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/test

Update: it seems to be related to the test data that's used in the **note** field, even if using batch payouts the following changed the result status:

```
{
  "sender_batch_header": {
    "sender_batch_id": "Payouts_2018_100007",
    "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
    "email_message": "You have received a payout! Thanks for using our service!"
  },
  "items":[
    {
      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
      "amount": {
        "value": "500",
        "currency": "MXN"
      },
      "note": "POSPYO001",
      "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
      "receiver": "ss36@business.example.com",
      "alternate_notification_method": {
        "phone": {
          "country_code": "52",
          "national_number": "4491110560"
        }
      },
      "notification_language": "sp-SP"
    }
  ]
}
```

A single payout looks like this:

```
{
  "sender_payout_header":
  {
    "sender_batch_id": "1524086406556",
    "email_subject": "This email is related to simulation"
  },
  "items": [
  {
    "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
    "receiver": "payouts-simulator-receiver@paypal.com",
    "note": "POSPYO001",
    "sender_item_id": "15240864065560",
    "amount":
    {
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": "1.00"
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it was because my country(India) name is present in supported countries list of PayPal but i got to know about PayPal Commerce Platform availability where it is not supporting India. Check below link

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/country-codes/?mark=countries#paypal-commerce-platform-availability

My work is only on sandbox account of paypal for testing so i simply created new test account of country US.

Possibly your paypal account is from any country listed in above link. Please check country of your main paypal account.