# Paypal Transactions in INR

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can I sent money in INR  using Paypal business account (REST API)

I have created an account from India in Paypal .But when I tried to sent money using sandbox account.Got error.

```
{
    "name": "PAYOUT_NOT_AVAILABLE",
    "message": "You live in a country that is not allowed to send this payout.",
}
```

Then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58206027/paypal-payout-not-available/58813763#58813763) and created a new account with country as UK.

Now I can call my payout API with

"currency": "GBP"
How can I do transactions in INR?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created an account from India in Paypal .But when I tried to sent money using sandbox account.Got error.

Are you referring to the live account that you used to sign in to https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

Or are you referring to the sandbox Business account on that list?

When testing in sandbox mode, the important thing is the country of the sandbox account on that list. You may need to create a new Indian Business account in the sandbox environment, and use that for Payouts.